# Run powershell scripts ".ps1 " on windows IoT core devices

Tags: powershell, iot, windows-iot-core-10

I am running Windows IoT core on a gateway, and want to run PowerShell scripts as .ps1 format in the windows iot core device,

I have written a simple PowerShell script to get the storage in a variable and print the variable

```
$a = Get-PSDrive
echo "$a"
```

Before that, I have connected my local IoT core device using the PowerShell IDE,

```
 net start WinRM
 Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 192.168.1.104
 Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.1.104 -Credential administrator
```

after this, I got the PowerShell of the windows IoT core device

```
[192.168.1.104]: PS C:\Data\Users\administrator.MINWINPC\Documents>
```

Now when I am running a single line of cmdlets like

```
192.168.1.104]: PS C:\Data\Users\administrator.MINWINPC\Documents>  Get-PSDrive
```

its working file its giving the output, but when i am trying this -

```
$a = Get-PSDrive
echo "$a"
```

This is giving the bellow error -

```
[192.168.1.104]: PS C:\Data\Users\administrator.MINWINPC\Documents>     $a = Get-PSDrive
echo "$a"
Alias C Cert Env Function HKCU HKLM U Variable WSMan
```

I need to run a PowerShell scripts in the IoT core device

Thanks for the answer, in the windows system its works just fine

This works perfectly  echo with " "

```
$a = "hi"
echo "about to start infinite loop"
while(1)
{
      echo "$a"
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 1.5
}


PS C:\Users\arnab.h.ghosh> C:\Users\arnab.h.ghosh\Pictures\loop.ps1
about to start infinite loop
hi
hi
hi
hi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following script:

```
$a = Get-PSDrive
echo $a
```

Here, `$a` is a variable to store the result of `Get-PSDrive`, you can not use quotation marks to echo the variable. Please see [Using variables to store objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/using-variables-to-store-objects?view=powershell-6).

Comment: replied in the post

Comment: @ArnabGhosh, in your updated post, the variable `$a` was set as a const string, but Get-PSDrive returns an object. It is different.